# Is AR Kit capable of subtracting 3D boolean differences?

Tags: scenekit, arkit

In 3D modeling software, it is possible to intersect two objects and then subtract the difference of one object from the other, making a hole in the first object in the shape of the second.

Is it possible to do this type of effect in real time using scene kit? I haven't seen documentation suggesting such, but I can think of a few useful applications right away such as a gun being able to shoot through a 3d wall leaving a hole which you can see through, or a passageway automatically clipping its geometry through an occlusion plane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the answer is no, but there is one trick that is similar to this which achieves the "hole in the shape of my 3d model" effect.

What you can do is make a copy of your 3d model, set the original to a higher rendering order and then change the opacity of the cloned object to 0.001. This will allow you to see through any objects it is covering.

A useful application of this is creating a plane or another geometry, to allow you to create a hole in a wall.

Here is an example:

[image]